# Spark binary classifications predictions accuracy

Tags: java, apache-spark, classification, prediction

I'm using Spark mlib for binary classification. I trained a model on 3000 pictures and can predict it is male or female 1/0.

```
final NaiveBayesModel model = NaiveBayes.train(training.rdd(), 1.0);
JavaRDD predictions = test.map(new Function<Vector, Double>() {
            @Override
            public Double call(Vector p) {
                return model.predict(p);
            }
        });
```

I have a question,what if a picture contains no person. For example a picture of a flower. I will be given a result male or female anyway. Is there a way to see the accuracy of current decision? For example this Vector is 30% male if we try to make prediction on a flower picture. Or I need to use multiclass classification like male/female/others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you state in your question, if you've currently trained your model to do binary classification, that's all it's going to do. You could do at least two different things:

1. train your model to predict three classes (`male`, `female`, `other`), as you suggest.
2. use two binary models, one which predicts between `human present`/`not present` and then only pass the `human present` results to a separate `male`/`female` classifier.

It's difficult to tell upfront which would be more effective, but since you're using `mllib`, it should be pretty straight forward to try them both out and see which one works better. Make sure to use a good `train/validation/test` split to compare.

Comment: You mean train a model to do binary classification like 'human present/not present' and then if predict is 'human present' then predict on the other trained model for 'male/female'?

Comment: @RuslanLomov Yes, that's a correct interpretation of option 2.